# Cómo seleccionar una fila de una tabla de MS Access para recorrer una tabla

Tags: php, ms-access

Estoy haciendo un script que me recorra una tabla entera de MS Access, desde PHP. El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
 for ($i=0; $i <$tablesize_pedidos_WS_integer ; $i++) { 
            $query="SELECT * from pedidos";
            $rs_pedidos_WS=mysqli_query($conWebService, $query);
            $pedidos_WS=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_pedidos_WS);
            var_dump($pedidos_WS);
            }
```

El problema es que en vez de recorrerme la tabla, me está devolviendo el primer pedido x veces (con sus respectivos campos, claro), cuando yo quiero que me recorra los distintos pedidos. Entiendo que eso es anidar dos bucles for (el que ya tengo, anidarle otro), pero no sé cómo decirle "i=primera fila de la tabla" y luego i++, para que me vaya recorriendo la tabla entera. ¿Alguna idea? Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entiendo que, donde dices MS Access, quieres decir MySQL porque utilizas `mysqli` e indicas que te funciona.

En ese caso, prueba así:

```
$query="SELECT * from pedidos";
$rs_pedidos_WS=mysqli_query($conWebService, $query);
$pedidos_WS=mysqli_fetch_all($rs_pedidos_WS);
var_dump($pedidos_WS);
```

No es necesario que definas tú mismo el bucle, PHP te lo pone más fácil con esta función:
https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Si te empeñas en usar `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`, también funcionaría:

```
$query="SELECT * from pedidos";
$rs_pedidos_WS=mysqli_query($conWebService, $query);
while($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_pedidos_WS))
    $pedidos_WS[]=$r;
var_dump($pedidos_WS);
```

Que irá almacenando, registro a registro, todo el contenido de la tabla en tu array `$pedidos_WS`.

Espero que te resulte útil. Cualquier duda, déjamela en los comentarios.

Comment: Pues básicamente ahora resulta que no tengo que sacar toda la tabla, sino sólo algunos registros. Esta es la query:

       $query="SELECT Marketplace, IdPedido, fecha, nombre cliente as nombre, direccion, DNI, CP, poblacion, provincia, telefono, idarticulo, descripcion, bultos, importe, impporte, costeportes, comision, Estado
        from pedidos";

Y este el código:    for ($i=0; $i <$tablesize_pedidos_WS_integer ; $i++) { 
            
            $rs_pedidos_WS=mysqli_query($conWebService, $query);
            $pedidos_WS=mysqli_fetch_all($rs_pedidos_WS);

Comment: echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$i."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$pedidos_WS[$i]["Marketplace"]."</td> <br>";
            echo "<td>".$pedidos_WS[$i]["IdPedido"]."</td> <br>";
            echo "<td>".$pedidos_WS[$i]["fecha"]."</td> <br>";

Así las estoy cogiendo, no pongo todas las líneas, simplemente como ejemplo. El caso que me da este error: Warning: mysqli_fetch_all() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given pero no comprendo por qué.

Comment: ¿Para qué sigues usando el `for`? Ya no te hace falta...