# Límite máximo de campos que puedo meter en un array en PHP

Tags: php, ms-access

Estoy leyendo una tabla de MS Access con PHP y estoy guardando todo en una matriz, y lo estoy recorriendo para mostrarlo para ver que efectivamente, me muestra lo que yo quiero. El código de recorrido es este:

```
  for ($i=0; $i <$tablesize_pedidos_WS_integer ; $i++) { 
            $query="SELECT * from pedidos";
            $rs_pedidos_WS=mysqli_query($conWebService, $query);
            $pedidos_WS=mysqli_fetch_all($rs_pedidos_WS);
```

y luego lo muestro. El caso es que quiero mostrar una variable, que es el campo 38, es decir, $pedidos_WS[$i][38] pero veo que el array $pedidos_WS con var_dump sólo me guarda 33 campos, y entonces me sale el típico error del offset. Estoy ejecutando esto en XAMPP. ¿Dónde puede estar el problema? Gracias.

Comment: Haces la query dentro de un bucle????? Por qué a cada vuelta del bucle vuelves a hacer un `select * from pedidos`? Si nunca cambias la query, no la hagas en el bucle, estás quemando recursos a lo loco. Por otro lado, imagino que llega a 33 porque es el valor de `$tablesize_pedidos_WS_integer`. Te recomiendo usar un log para ir viendo el valor de las variables ( o usar un debugger, pero no sé con qué programas así que...). Es imposible ayudarte más sin saber qué vale cada cosa. Por último, te recomiendo otra vez hacer la query fuera del bucle y usar un while para recorrerla, no ese for

Comment: Primero saca el query del bucle. Prueba con mysql_fetch_all($re_pedidos_WS, MYSQLI_ASSOC). Después puedes utilizar un foreach ($pedidos_WS as $row) {echo $row['campo'];}

Comment: A ver. $tablesize_pedidos_WS_integer tiene 9000 registros, y cada registro 43 campos. El problema es que al recorrer cada registro, sólo recorre 33 campos, no sé por qué. La query ya la he sacado del bucle y, para mi sorpresa, tarda exactamente lo mismo en ejecutar en el servidor (5 min 20 segundos).

Comment: Intenta que te muestre alguno de los últimos campos con echo $row['nombre del campo'];

Comment: @Sergio acabo de responderte aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/395802